# The module at index [1] is of type "undefined". Check your import statements and the type of the module

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, circular-dependency

I heve a problem with circular dependency in NestJs. Error:

```
Scope [AppModule -> PlanModule -> TaskModule] +17ms
Error: Nest cannot create the UserModule instance.
The module at index [1] of the UserModule "imports" array is undefined.
```

What I tried:

- Use *forwardRef* in resolver file in both user and task files in construcor:

```
@Inject(forwardRef(() => TaskService))
private readonly tasksService: TaskService
```

- Implements *OnModuleInit* interface:

```
onModuleInit() {
  this.userService = this.moduleRef.get(UserService);
}
```

- Use imports without *index.ts* file:

```
import { TaskModule } from '../task/task.module';
```

**user.module**

```
@Module({
  providers: [UserService, UserResolver],
  exports: [UserService],
  imports: [JournalModule, PlanModule, TaskModule],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

**task.module**

```
@Module({
  providers: [TaskService, TaskResolver],
  exports: [TaskService],
  imports: [UserModule],
})
export class TaskModule {}
```

**plan.module**

```
@Module({
  providers: [PlanService, PlanResolver, GoalResolver],
  imports: [TaskModule, ProgramModule],
  exports: [PlanService],
})
export class PlanModule {}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `UserModule` import the `TaskModule` and the `TaskModule` imports the `UserModule`, so you need to set up forward references for these module imports *along with* the service injections. It would look like this:

**user.module.ts**

```js
@Module({
  providers: [UserService, UserResolver],
  exports: [UserService],
  imports: [JournalModule, PlanModule, forwardref(() => TaskModule)],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

**task.module.ts**

```js
@Module({
  providers: [TaskService, TaskResolver],
  exports: [TaskService],
  imports: [forwardRef(() => UserModule)],
})
export class TaskModule {}
```